# Query to check how many unique users meet two conditions in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables - firstly a users table with unique user IDs; for example:

| UserID | Email address |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 |  |
| 1235 |  |
| 1236 |  |

I have another table, an engagements table, which also shows the user ID, as well as each engagement on a separate row. Here’s a simplified example:

| UserID | ObjectID | ObjectName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10 | Event email |
| 1234 | 11 | Event registration |
| 1234 | 12 | Promotion |
| 1235 | 10 | Event email |
| 1235 | 11 | Event registration |
| 1236 | 12 | Promotion |
| 1236 | 10 | Event email |

I want to create a query that tells me how many individuals have engaged with item object ID 10 as well as 11.

The query I have at the moment is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.UserID
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Engagements.UserID = Users.UserID
WHERE Engagements.UserID = ‘10’
  AND Engagements.UserID = ‘11’
```

However, this is returning no results. Do I need to change the way the join is set up?

Comment: Change AND in your condition to OR. Basically, what you are saying here is that in one row, UserID needs to be both 10 and 11 which can't be true ever so no row is selected. You should say that it needs to be 10 OR 11.

Comment: I would recommend reading few tutorials on WHERE clause and logical operators used with it (documentation on them as well). i.e. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/logical-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I'd expect a syntax error here. Should be `LEFT JOIN Engagements ON Engagements.UserID = Users.UserID...`.

Comment: Also move the Engagements conditions from WHERE to ON if you want true LEFT JOIN result. (As it is now, you'll get regular INNER JOIN result.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to involve the Users table, since you only want to know the number of UserID's having both 10 and 11 objectid's. I.e. all information is found in Engagements table.

Simply do a `GROUP BY`, and use `HAVING` with `COUNT DISTINCT` to make sure both 10 and 11 are there.

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select UserId
    from Engagements
    where ObjectID in (10, 11)
    group by UserId
    having count(distinct ObjectID) = 2
) dt
```

Comment: Thank you - this is really, really helpful. I also want to find out how many IDs have 10 but not 11 . I have tried different variations, such as 'where ObjectID in (10, -11)'  and 'where ObjectID in (10) and not ObjectID in (11)', but each time I keep getting the same result as 'ObjectID = 10'. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Skip the WHERE clause, instead use case expressions in the HAVING to do conditional counting. Or use EXCEPT (similar to UNION.) Or ask another question. You can put the link here.

Answer (score -2):

The first statement below will give you the amount of times a User interacted with an object (as I don't know the constraints around the table and if a user can only engage with an Object once or more than once).

So for example, if the `Enagements` table has 2 records for `UserId` `1234` and `ObjectId` `10`, then by your question you're not concerned with the amount of times `ObjectId` `10` was engaged by `UserId` `1234`. Instead, you only want the amount of users itself that engaged with that object, not the amount of times a specific user engaged with it.

The second statement will then group it to give you the amount of users that engaged with that Object.

```sql
select ObjectId, UserId 
    into #TempUniqueEngagementsPerUser
    from Enagagement 
    Where objectId in (10,11)
    group by ObjectId, UserId
    
select ObjectId, Count(UserId) as AmountOfUsers
    from #TempUniqueEngagementsPerUser
    group by ObjectId
```